# pc software for fake gps on iphone and android devices

Tags: android, ios, gps, mocks

Im developing an application for IOS and android, that is based on locations

for testing my app i need a pc (windows and mac) software to mock locations on real Iphone and android devices

i need the software to run on my pc in order to send locations when my app is in foreground/background/locked screen

Im willing to pay for the software